# Proper workflow for refreshing expired JWT token automatically on request using Axios interceptor and httpOnly cookies

Tags: javascript, axios, jwt

Hello I'm trying to figure out what is the proper workflow to refresh an expired JWT token using Axios and httpOnly cookies.
I've seen some tutorials that make a request to the server and if they get an "expired token response" then they send a 401 "refresh token" request.

But I thought is better to simply check if the token has expired on the client,  this way we are not wasting an HTTP request for the server to respond that it has expired.

This is the code I have so far. I'm wondering if there is a better or simpler way of doing it. Of if there is something else that I'm not considering.
Many thanks

```
// Create Axios instance for Backend API
const BACKEND_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/'
const API = axios.create({
    baseURL: BACKEND_URL,
})

// Axios interceptor to refresh token when expired
API.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
    // If Authorization header exists get token from header and decode it to get expiration time
    const authorizationHeader = config.headers.common.Authorization
    if (authorizationHeader) {
        const token = authorizationHeader.replace('Bearer ', '')
        const expiration = jwt_decode(token).exp

        // If token has expired get a new one and update Authorization Header
        if (Date.now()/1000 >= expiration) {
            // Delete Authorization header to prevent infinite loop
            delete API.defaults.headers.common.Authorization
            // Send /token/refresh request to backend
            const response = await API.post(`auth/token/refresh/`, {}, {withCredentials: true})
            // Update header in current request
            config.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${response.data.access}`
            // Update header in the axios instance
            API.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${response.data.access}`
        }
    }
    return config
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach seems OK, though, if I'm not wrong, this isn't a standard OAuth refresh flow, right? In my opinion it's always better to implement standards, especially when security is involved.

There is one issue that you may run into with this approach. If the `expiration` is one second from now your code will not fire, but by the time the access token reaches the server it may be expired. This will happen also if there are differences in clocks between the client machine and the server.